# Influx writting few tag values into tag key for point

Tags: ruby, influxdb

How can I write a few tag values into one tag key for point, and is it possible?
I've tried to send tag values as an array, and influx just converts it to string.

`>show tag values with key = Some_Key`

```
name: measurement
key              value
---              -----
Some_Key [1, 156, 157, 159, 160, 162, 170, 174, 177]
```

I want to add these values split. How i can do it ? 
I write points by ruby api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Tags can only be strings.

If you want to make a string representation of the array you can convert to JSON first.

*however* it is likely a bad idea to make this a tag and not a field, because your cardinality will increase a lot and when that happens, the database will become very slow. If you feel you must make it a tag, then you should consider adding a retention policy so that the data gets deleted after a short while.